# This line is crashing my firebase signup app.....**mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();**

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-developer-api

When i remove this line **mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();** then the activity_signup.xml runs in my android studio but when i run
the program with this line then it stops working and crash.

Since i cannot develop the app without it , what should be done?

Some of the dependencies for other parts of program like **location, sms, uploading pics**

This is my **SignUp.java**

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        emailId=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btnSignUp=findViewById(R.id.button);
        tvSignIn=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

This is my **Build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.getlocation"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error i get in **run** part where line 29 is initializing FirebaseAuth instance

```
    Process: com.example.getlocation, PID: 11123
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.getlocation-2/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)

        at com.example.getlocation.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:29)

        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1513)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6210)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old version of these dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

You should make sure that **all** of your Firebase dependencies are at the latest version as described by the [release notes in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  They should normally be upgraded in tandem with each other.